# System permissions

Tags: android, permissions, installation

Is there any way to get access to /system/app or /data/app folders without root? I need possibility to install my app into that folders but without rooting a phone.

1. Is it possible to do it if I sign my app with system sertificate and get system permission?
2. How to sign my app with system sertificate and get system permission?
3. Will my app run on NON-rooted devices with system signing?

Answer (score 3):

Without rooting your device or utilizing some sort of exploit, it is not possible to access these folders. One thing to keep in mind is when you first install an application it goes directly to `data/app/`. A note about `system/app` is that these are build specific applications that are bundled and protected on a device and cannot be removed.